# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" error when running from terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc, classpath

I have a program that I run from Eclipse successfully.

However, when I want to run it from terminal, I encounter the famous error:

> "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

on this line:

```
Class drvClass = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

---

---

PS:

I have the following in CLASSPATH:

```
/oracle/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar
```

Also note that I compile it successfully (javac Test2.java). Then when I run it (java Test2), I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Test2

So I run:

```
java -classpath ~/Desktop/JDBC2/src Test2
```

It runs, but I get the above "ClassNotFoundException" though.

Comment: Include the driver jar in the classpath

Comment: Did you add to the `-classpath` parameter?

Comment: Yes, if you mean when running: java -classpath ~/Desktop/JDBC2/src Test2

Comment: Using -classpath is overriding your CLASSPATH variable.

Comment: Otherwise, as I mentioned, I get the other error ("Error: Could not find or load main class Test2").

Comment: So try -classpath ~/Desktop/JDBC2/src:/oracle/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar, for example. You need both in the classpath, and like I said, -classpath is overriding your CLASSPATH variable.

Comment: That's right. I compile it successfully and have Test2.class file there.

Comment: @yngwietiger: That works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @yngwietiger mentioned above in the comments, using -classpath parameter when running the .class file, **overrides the original CLASSPATH** and the predefined ojdbc6.jar file. So we need to mention both when running:

```
java -classpath ~/Desktop/JDBC2/src:/oracle/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar Test2
```

Or, as a better solution, we can add the current path to CLASSPATH (note the colon and dot at the end):

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:.
```

And, in order to run, we just need to type:

```
Java Test2
```

Comment: you missed ';' at the end of .jar

Answer (score 1):

I found this question tricky: the reason is related to semicolon after jar file address.
At first I changed the directory of MySample.java to another directory (you can don't do that) like C:\ 
then I removed package address from the source code, at the end I run this command in cmd

```
java -cp path_to_oracle_driver.jar; MySample
```

P.S. If you want run it from terminal you have to remove `package PackageAddress` from the source code and compile it again.